# Executar Procedure através de um WebService VB.Net

Tags: web-service

Estou fazendo um WebService para acessar uma procedure que fiz. Estou tendo dificuldades por ser novo na área. Primeiramente fiz a classe com as propriedades publicas que iriam armazenar os valores para mais parte passar para procedure que por sua vez vai inserir dados no banco.

Aí está minha classe

```
Public Class clsMaquinario

    Private _container As String
    Private _statusMaq As String
    Private _usuario As String
    Private _data As String

    Public Property Container() As String
        Get
            Return _container
        End Get
        Set(ByVal value As String)
            _container = value
        End Set
    End Property

    Public Property StatusMaq() As String
        Get
            Return _statusMaq
        End Get
        Set(ByVal value As String)
            _statusMaq = value
        End Set
    End Property

    Public Property Usario() As String
        Get
            Return _usuario
        End Get
        Set(ByVal value As String)
            _usuario = value
        End Set
    End Property

    Public Property Data() As String
        Get
            Return _data
        End Get
        Set(ByVal value As String)
            _data = value
        End Set
    End Property


End Class
```

Estou fazendo isso com base em outro pronto. Minha duvida é a seguinte, coloco o método para acessar o banco e executar a procedure na própria classe? 
E se sim, como? Pois tenho um exemplo que me foi dado para seguir só que sem procedure, enviando o select direto para o Banco. O Exemplo é esse:

```
Function LIB_VAZIO_EXPORTACAO_INTERNO(ByVal Container As String) As clsLibVazioExportacao

        Dim StrSql As String
        Dim libVazio As New clsLibVazioExportacao
        Dim rscmdAux As SqlClient.SqlDataReader
        Dim acessa As New AcessoDAO.Banco

        Try
            StrSql = ""
            StrSql = StrSql & "Select Cod_Armador, Nome_Armador, Conteiner, Tipo_Iso, "
            StrSql = StrSql & "Tipo, Tara, Mgw, N_Booking, N_Lacre, Cod_Porto, "
            StrSql = StrSql & "Nome_Porto, Dt_Saida, Nome_Exportador, Num_Intercambio "
            StrSql = StrSql & "from v_lib_exportacao_interno "
            StrSql = StrSql & "where Conteiner = '" & Container & "'"

            rscmdAux = acessa.RetornaDataReader(StrSql)

     ............

        Return libVazio

    End Function
```

Comment: Jonas dê uma olhada neste exemplo: http://csharpbrasil.com.br/criando-e-consumindo-web-service-em-c-sharp-parte-1/

Comment: Bacana o artigo, explica bem o funcionamento de um webservice. Creio que não estou conseguindo dar continuidade por não saber o basico sobre isso, por ja me darem um código pronto... Alguem pode me ajudar com a resolução e tentar me explicar por que ? Obrigado

Comment: para você acessar a sua classe do webservice, você pode criar um método static e acessar ele veja o exemplo bem simples. http://pastebin.com/Bbp4s5J6